# Do the engines/rockets of Kylo Ren's Shuttle change color?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, spaceship, kylo-ren

Screenshot from the film:

[image: movie still, red engines]

Screenshot from the trailer:

[image: trailer still, yellow engines]

Image of the toy:

[image: toy image, blue engines]

So, what the deal here? Do the color of the engines change during the movie?

Comment: Would anyone care to comment how I could improve this question?

Comment: I think it is a fair question.

Answer (score 3):

I was really tempted to make this a comment, but I figured a should make it an answer.

### The long answer

is that there is lot playing at our minds when we see color and contrast is a big source deception of what we are really seeing with our eyes.

Take this example from this [web page here](http://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/color4a.html):

[image]

All the blue dots on the cube are exactly the same color. But , to our eyes they certainly look different.

It says on in the link:

> The figure at right illustrates both perceptual effects in a single
>   figure. **The three blue dots at the center of each cube face have**
>   **exactly the same luminance on your computer screen.** (That is, if the
>   colors are sampled with the Photoshop color picker, they yield
>   identical hexidecimal or RGB values.) However, the upper face of the
>   cube appears the most brightly illuminated and therefore the blue dot
>   within it, because it has a much **lower luminance relative** to the
>   yellow dots around it, and **so appears darkened** and attached to the
>   surface. The cube face on the right is in deep shadow, and therefore
>   the same blue dot has a much greater luminance relative to the
>   shadowed surface around it, causing it to appear to glow dimly as a
>   light.

And then there is color shifts produced by chromatic induction:

[image]

> In each example, all four color bars above or below the small dots are
>   identical image colors on your computer monitor. However, the wide
>   (low frequency) bar on the dark background **appears lighter** than the
>   wide bar on the **light background**, because chromatic contrast makes
>   color and background appear more different. At high spatial
>   frequencies, the thin (high frequency) bar on the dark background
>   appears darker than the thin bar on the light background, because
>   chromatic assimilation makes color and background appear more similar.
>   Roughly, **color vision enhances contrast between color areas large**
>   enough to count as different objects, and suppresses contrast between
>   color areas small enough to be texture on a single surface.

And finally there is color shifts, or differences in chromatic contrast and assimilation on the y/b and r/g opponent functions:

[image]

> The top of the image shows this difference in edge contrast in the
>   familiar related color presentations. **The bottom of the image shows an**
>   **identical color** pattern presented in a black/white version (example
>   b), or in yellow/violet (a) or red/green (c) at equal lightness and
>   chroma. The r/g stimulus still produces color separation at high
>   spatial frequencies when lightness or chroma contrasts are minimal; a
>   comparable yellow/violet stimulus produces assimilation — an
>   apparently solid color area.

Looking at your two examples taken from the movie, we can only assume that being shown against a lighter background (the sky) and a darker background (blackness of space) that a lot of these phenomenons could be playing tricks of our eyes.

One caveat, I did not test the actual colors to see if they were actually two different colors, the reason being is that in the production stage they could well have changed to hue to get a special affect for the entire picture and while that may have changed the perceived color of the engines , it may have simply just been overlooked.

### Short answer,

My ship was really burning oil that day and when the ship is using maximum power to leave a planets gravity, the engines burn much hotter give off a red color when it needs a service. As it was , it was well over due for a service, but the first order put all their money into that big planet ending weapon on Starkiller Base, so budget cuts from Snoke would only allow as service every 100,000,000,000 miles.

Comment: You're username and that last paragraph just made my day! :)

Comment: @RedCaio, LOL, glad you liked it.